# Apache security challenge, rejecting specific requests without blocking IP

Tags: apache, security, webserver

I have been trying to solve a big problem for the last 2 weeks with one of our servers (apache 2.2 , windows, php).

The client using our system is a contact center firm. 
 They have about 120 operators, all connect to our websever with the same IP, their outgoing IP.

We have been suffering DoS attacks from some of these operators. 
 These are simple, browser attacks , namely 5 or 10 operators will just hold 
 F5 key and bombard the server with requests when they shouldnt.

There is very little we can do to improve performance of these specific url's the attackers are using. This is a software, not a public portal, so a lot of screens have a good amount of processing and real time querying in them.

We did manage to produce a php protection which will recognize the multiple requests and blacklist the user in php, after the user is logged in, by using a control mechanism with a cookie containing the userID in our software.

This works to some extent, but it’s a little "too late" since the request have already been sent and processed by the webserver. 
Even if the response is now minimal and causes no more trouble to the server, ideally we would like something EXACTLY like mod_evasive, but for rejecting single requests instead of blocking the IP.

Exemplifying : if a user calls the same url, 5 times, in a 3 second spawn, we will reject every next request for 30 seconds, but only the requests by that user (identified by some cookie).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is more of an administrative problem than a technical problem - tell your customers to educate their users.

But if you really want to do that in software, some scheme like the following should work:

- Give each of your users a different cookie (you're already doing that?).
- Create a database table that has cookies and "request counts".
- Whenever your software starts processing a request, if the request count for that session is > 3 (or a number you think is appropriate), abort immediately, set the request count to 30, and give an error message to the user. Especially don't do all that expensive processing stuff.
- If the request count is less than 3, increase it by one and process the request normally.
- Have some cron job decrease by one all request counts that are >1. Depending on the typical use case of your software, run this once per minute, or once every few seconds in a loop that queries the database, then sleeps for a while.

Tune the parameters to your software, or course.